# difference in file tranfer speed due to difference in file features?

Tags: 22.04, rsync, transfer, file-properties

I'm using Try Ubuntu on a USB drive to use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
This way I'm copying files from an external disc in Ext4 file system to an internal disc in NTFS file system.

I have two folders (folder1 and folder2) with around 800000 files each. Files in folder2 are created from files in folder1. 'file' gives 'ASCII text' as output in both cases. Files in folder1 contain only 5 columns of numbers. Files in folder2 contain a 4-line header and 9 columns of numbers.

Using `rsync -a` with folder1 takes some hours. However, using the same method on folder2 would take several days at a rate of 1-2 files per second.

Why does it happen?
Is there a way to transfer files in folder2 faster?

Here you are more details on the files in the different folders from the `stat` function

- files in folder1

  ```
  Size: 138078      Blocks: 280        IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: 851h/2129d    Inode: 92254606    Links: 1
  Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)
  ```
- files in folder2

  ```
  Size: 394398      Blocks: 784        IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: 851h/2129d    Inode: 146939637   Links: 1
  Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)
  ```

And from `ls -l`

- files in folder1

  ```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 138078
  ```
- files in folder2

  ```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 394398
  ```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try compressing the files first with `gzip` or `bzip2` or something similar.  There's always the trade-off between compression and decompression time versus transfer speed.  I think `rsync` does a comparison between the source and destination; if you know the destination doesn't have the files, you can just use `scp` and do a copy.  That might help as well...

Comment: is that the full command? If not add `--inplace` (and avoid using compression directly using rsync (so no `-z`) if it is a local copy)

Comment: @Ray thanks! I have now tried both scp and gzip. Unfortunately, still the same behaviour.
gzip trial: 
for filename in /folder2/*.file_ext; do gzip -k -c $filename > "/destination/$(basename "$filename").gz";done
scp trial: 
scp /folder2/ /destination/
In both cases, the first 100-200 files are copied very fast and then only 1-2 files per second. Same behaviour as with rsync -a.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks!
What command do you refer to? rsync -a /full_path_folder2/ /destination/ is what I used.
What do you mean by local copy?

Comment: local as in your network. compression is mosttimes extra overhead if you do it directly with rsync (the -z option)